# Using StaticFileHandler to host a file on Tornado Python

Tags: python, file, static, tornado

Hi I am attempting to use StaticFileHandler in Tornado and for the most part its working, except its outputting the file (.csv) in a webpage when I click download. The only way I can save the file is Right clicking and saying save target as (but this doesn't work in all browsers).

How can I force the file to be downloaded?
I know I need to somehow set the header of the StaticFileHandler like this:

```
    self.set_header('Content-Type','text-csv')
    self.set_header('Content-Disposition','attachment')
```

But I have no idea how to set it because it is a default handler.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Extend the web.StaticFileHandler

```
class StaticFileHandler(web.StaticFileHandler):
    def get(self, path, include_body=True):
        if [some csv check]:
            # your code from above, or anything else custom you want to do
            self.set_header('Content-Type','text-csv')  
            self.set_header('Content-Disposition','attachment')

        super(StaticFileHandler, self).get(path, include_body)
```

Dont forget to use your extended class in the handler!

Comment: note that this might work, but that the documentation of web.StaticFileHandler explicitly discourages to overwrite the get method. The  classmethod 'set_extra_headers(path)' is supported and can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since comments are liable to be deleted, the *correct* solution (as described in the comment by [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/579952/jan)) is:

> [T]he documentation of web.StaticFileHandler explicitly discourages to overwrite the get method. The classmethod 'set_extra_headers(path)' is supported and can be used instead.

The correct solution would look like this:

```py
class StaticFileHandler(web.StaticFileHandler):
    @classmethod
    def set_extra_headers(self, path):
        if path.endswith('.csv'):
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text-csv')  
            self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
```