# How can Tornado serve a single static file at an arbitrary location?

Tags: python, tornado, static-files

I am developing a simple web app with Tornado. It serves some dynamic files and some static ones. The dynamic ones are not a problem, but I am having trouble serving a static file. What I am looking to do is to serve the file /path/to/foo.json when the /foo.json URL is accessed.

Note that /path/to/foo.json is outside the document root. In Apache I would just set up an Alias. With Tornado I have:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/dynamic\.html', MyService, dict(param = 12345)),
    (r'/(foo\.json)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '/path/to/foo.json'})
    ])
```

I added the regex group operator `()` to satisfy Tornado, which threw an exception otherwise. But now, when I access /foo.json, I get a 404: File Not Found.

Tests reveal that Tornado is attempting to use the path provided as a root directory to which it appends foo.json, implying my file could be found if it were at /path/to/foo.json/foo.json. Close, but not quite.

I suppose I could shorten my path to simply "/path/to", which will trigger a fetch of /path/to/foo.json upon the /foo.json URL, but this forces me to use the same name in the URL as on the filesystem. How can I just do a simple, arbitrary, URL to file mapping?

I have done some research on this, reading the documentation for [tornado.web.Application](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application) and [tornado.web.StaticFilehandler](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler), plus some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165665/using-tornado-how-do-i-serve-static-files-and-serve-a-favicon-ico-from-a-differ) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787499/tornado-static-files-serving-url-configuration) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725025/using-staticfilehandler-to-host-a-file-on-tornado-python). Nothing is quite my use case.

Comment: So by arbitrary file mapping what you want is to map, say, the URL `yourdomain.com/path/to/foo.json` to `yourfilesystem/path/to/bar.json`? I think you should include that in your question (i.e., use different name in the example, not using `foo.json` in both URL and file system)

Comment: I mention this in my second to last paragraph, @justhalf, but perhaps it could be clearer.

Comment: Yes, my point is to include what you refer to in your second last paragraph in your example. Because your example doesn't really represent your real question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MyFileHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):
    def initialize(self, path):
        self.dirname, self.filename = os.path.split(path)
        super(MyFileHandler, self).initialize(self.dirname)

    def get(self, path=None, include_body=True):
        # Ignore 'path'.
        super(MyFileHandler, self).get(self.filename, include_body)

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/foo\.json', MyFileHandler, {'path': '/path/to/foo.json'})
])

app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The URL pattern and the filename need not be related, you could do this and it would work just as well:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/jesse\.txt', MyFileHandler, {'path': '/path/to/foo.json'})
])
```

Comment: Note that subclassing StaticFileHandler can be delicate, and it's better to leave `get()` alone.  Instead, the classmethod `get_absolute_path` is a better method to override here (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.get_absolute_path)

Comment: I like this approach, and it is working well for me. But I am intrigued by the approach of overriding `get_absolute_path`. @BenDarnell, can you provide an example?

Comment: This is untested, but it illustrates the general idea: https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/8553378

Comment: But get_absolute_path is a class method, there's no 'self'.

Answer (score 14):

StaticFileHandler expects two arguments, so if you want a single url (/foo.json) to be mapped to your file path you can use:

```
app = tornado.web.Application([
(r'/foo.json()', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '/path/to/foo.json'})
])
```

The regex will match `/foo.json` and send the empty capture group `()`, which will cause the filepath to be used as is.  When the capture group is not empty, `/path/to/foo.json` will be treated as a directory `/path/to/foo.json/`, and the handler will try to match whatever is within the capture group to a file name in that directory.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I like the simplicity of this approach. +1.

Comment: Why not without the brackets?

Answer (score 6):

StaticFileHandler gets is file name from the regex capturing group and the directory name from its path argument.  It will work if you use `/path/to/` as the path:

```
(r'/(foo\.json)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '/path/to/'})
```

StaticFileHandler is designed for cases where URLs and filenames match; if you can't arrange to have this file available on disk under the same name you want to serve it as you'll have to use a custom handler.