# Python SimpleHTTPServer in production

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

I want to serve static files with Python. Is the Python 3 `http.server` suitable for use in production? If not, why not? And what are my alternatives?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: or you can use tornado library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248222/how-can-tornado-serve-a-single-static-file-at-an-arbitrary-location

Comment: What sort of load are you expecting?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server

> Warning: http.server is not recommended for production. It only
>   implements basic security checks.

First of all you don't need python at all to serve static files. Just use a real HTTP Server like Apache or NGinx. If you want a quick solution just look for a docker container with a pre-configured image suitable for your needs. Here is the [NGinx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). Definitely docker is a must have 
tool that you will not regret to learn.

```
$ docker run --name mysite-nginx -v /mysite:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

Comment: `you don't need python at all to serve static files. Just use a real HTTP Server like Apache` -- I arrived at this question to see if it's possible to "just serve a folder" without invoking the behemoth that is _Apache_... if you don't need any features

Comment: I honestly just want to know if I can run a very VERY simple http api (single get single post command thats it) that only I will ever actually use. And I want this server to easilly be started and stopped in another python script, SimpleHTTPServer seemed like the answer but the warning in the documentation makes me quite concerned that it's a huge vulnerability risk to use (since the port will be exposed to the internet obviously). and as the other comment says, I really don't want to invoke a BEHEMOTH like apache for such a small tiny scale personal use.

Comment: A docker wrapped nginx is light to operate. You can also benefit from some auto-restart, log-rotate and the like. SimpleHttpServer will do the trick, but you will end up ssh-ing into that box often to babysit it.